# Codename One Unable to use jar

Tags: import, jar, codenameone

Currently I have placed my .jar file under native/android (and native/javase) but when I try to import the libraries (e.g import org.jivesoftware...), it will not show up. I can't access any of the libraries. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code completion won't work just like native OS code completion shouldn't work for native API's. But this will be compiled on the server and produce the working app.

A "trick" we do is send a build with "include source" checked then open the result in the native OS IDE and implement the native interface there. Then just copy the up to date native interface back to Codename One.